# Show five posts per category on wordpress home page

Tags: wordpress

I am displaying the post category wise on the homepage. I am able to prin the post category wise but i want to limit the post by 5 in each category how to do that:

Here is my code:

```
 $querystr = "SELECT * from wp_posts as wp INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships as wtr on wtr.object_id=wp.ID INNER JOIN wp_terms as wt on wtr.term_taxonomy_id=wt.term_id where wt.term_id IN (8,16,17) order by wt.term_id, wp.ID DESC
         ";

         $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
        $tem=""; 
         if ($pageposts): ?>
          <?php global $post; ?>
          <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
            <?php setup_postdata($post); $b=$post->name;
                if($tem !=$b){
                $tem=$b;
                ?>
            <h3 style="border-bottom:2px solid #3b8b98;" ><span style="background:#3b8b98;width:30%;"><?php echo $tem;?></span></h3>
            <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
             <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
               <i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i>&nbsp;<?php the_title(); ?></a>



            </div>
            <?php } else {?>

                <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
             <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
              <i class="fas fa-hand-point-right"></i>&nbsp;<?php the_title(); ?></a>



            </div>
            <?php
            } endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Use WP_Query to get the posts https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: what about first getting the categories and then showing 5 from each category? will this work out for you? Or you want to output the latest posts but don't want to show more than 5 from each category?

You can also have a look at this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/907/using-wp-query-to-query-multiple-categories-with-limited-posts-per-category

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP_Query wordpress function to get your desired result.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 4, 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
```

Add arguments in above example as per your requirement.